# How to optimize a query in SQL Server? The query takes 2 minutes to run, but I need the query to run in seconds

Tags: sql-server

In this query, only one table `AssetAttributes` takes 1 minute 54 seconds. This table contains 1782895 records.

I am selecting columns `AssetAttributeID, AssetAttributeName, AssetAttributeOwner, AssetAttributeParentID, AssetAttributeTypeID, AssetAttributeTypeName` from the `AssetAttribute` table.

```
SELECT     
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeID, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeName, 
    ISNULL(AssetAttributesFriendly.AssetAttributeFriendlyName, AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeName) AS FriendlyAssetAttributeName, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeOwner, Assets.AssetName, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeParentID, 
    Categories.CategoryName, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeTypeID, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeTypeName, 
    AssetAttributes.Active, 
    AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeDefinitionID, 
    Categories.CategoryParentID, Categories.CategoryOwner, 
    Categories.CategoryDefinitionID, Categories.Active AS CategoriesActive, 
    Assets.ChannelId AS AssetPlantID, 
    Categories.ChannelId AS CategoryPlantID, 
    AssetAttributes.ChannelId AS AssetAttributePlantID
FROM   
    AssetAttributes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AssetAttributesFriendly ON AssetAttributesFriendly.AssetAttributeID = AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeID 
                            AND AssetAttributesFriendly.plantid = AssetAttributes.ChannelId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Categories ON AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeParentID = Categories.CategoryID        
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Assets ON AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeOwner = Assets.AssetID
```

Comment: Are there any indexes on key columns used in left join

Comment: Do you really need all 1.78M records? Ideally filter AssetAttributes down on some fields that's part of an indexes

Comment: FROM   
    AssetAttributes with(nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AssetAttributesFriendly with(nolock) ON AssetAttributesFriendly.AssetAttributeID = AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeID 
                            AND AssetAttributesFriendly.plantid = AssetAttributes.ChannelId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Categories with(nolock) ON AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeParentID = Categories.CategoryID        
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Assets with(nolock) ON AssetAttributes.AssetAttributeOwner = Assets.AssetID

Comment: try this above code